# Preforming A Segue From TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I made a tableview that I have a search bar on the filters out the cells. I was wondering how I could make each individual cell go to a detail view and show a image.

Here is the code.

```
#import "SearchBar.h"

@interface SearchBar ()

@end

@implementation SearchBar

{
NSMutableArray *totalStrings;
NSMutableArray *filteredStrings;
BOOL isFiltered;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

{
    self.mySearchBar.delegate = self;
    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self;

    totalStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:


                    @"Apple - AAPL - Buy", @"Zacks Rank: Hold                        AAPL : Apple",
                    @"The Street Rank: Buy                AAPL : Apple",
                    @"MarketWatch Rank: Hold          AAPL : Apple",
                    @"InvestorPlace Rank: Hold         AAPL : Apple",
                    @"Nasdaq Rank: Buy                     AAPL : Apple",
                    @"Target Price: $135                    AAPL : Apple",
                    @"Our Pick - Strong Buy                AAPL : Apple",


                    @"Google - GOOG - Buy", @"Zacks Rank: Hold                        GOOG : Google",
                    @"The Street Rank: Hold               GOOG : Google",
                    @"MarketWatch Rank: Buy           GOOG : Google",
                    @"InvestorPlace Rank: Buy          GOOG : Google",
                    @"Nasdaq Rank: Buy                     GOOG : Google",
                    @"Target Price: $880                    GOOG : Google",
                    @"Our Pick - Strong Buy               GOOG : Google",


                    @"Amazon - AMZN - Buy", @"Zacks Rank: Hold                        AMZN : Amazon",
                    @"The Street Rank: Hold               AMZN : Amazon",
                    @"MarketWatch Rank: Buy           AMZN : Amazon",
                    @"InvestorPlace Rank: Buy          AMZN : Amazon",
                    @"Nasdaq Rank: Buy                     AMZN : Amazon",
                    @"Target Price: $735                    AMZN : Amazon",
                    @"Our Pick - Buy                       AMZN : Amazon",


                    @"Facebook - FB - Buy", @"Zacks Rank: Buy                        FB : Facebook",
                    @"The Street Rank: Hold               FB : Facebook",
                    @"MarketWatch Rank: Buy           FB : Facebook",
                    @"InvestorPlace Rank: Buy          FB : Facebook",
                    @"Nasdaq Rank: Buy                     FB : Facebook",
                    @"Target Price: $130                    FB : Facebook",
                    @"Our Pick - Strong Buy                  FB : Facebook",


                    @"Johnson & Johnson - JNJ - Hold", @"Zacks Rank: Hold                        JNJ : Johnson",
                    @"The Street Rank: Buy                JNJ : Johnson",
                    @"MarketWatch Rank: Hold          JNJ : Johnson",
                    @"InvestorPlace Rank: Buy           JNJ : Johnson",
                    @"Nasdaq Rank: Buy                     JNJ : Johnson",
                    @"Target Price: $111                     JNJ : Johnson",
                    @"Our Pick - Buy                        JNJ : Johnson",


                    @"Exxon Mobil - XOM - Hold", @"Zacks Rank: Hold                        XOM : Exxon",
                    @"The Street Rank: Hold               XOM : Exxon",
                    @"MarketWatch Rank: Hold           XOM : Exxon",
                    @"InvestorPlace Rank: Hold          XOM : Exxon",
                    @"Nasdaq Rank: Hold                     XOM : Exxon",
                    @"Target Price: $84                    XOM : Exxon",
                    @"Our Pick - Hold                    XOM : Exxon",


                    @"Netflix - NFLX - Hold", @"Zacks Rank: Hold                        NFLX : Netflix",
                    @"The Street Rank: Hold               NFLX : Netflix",
                    @"MarketWatch Rank: Hold           NFLX : Netflix",
                    @"InvestorPlace Rank: Buy          NFLX : Netflix",
                    @"Nasdaq Rank: Buy                     NFLX : Netflix",
                    @"Target Price: $125                    NFLX : Netflix",
                    @"Our Pick - Hold                   NFLX : Netflix",


                    @"Twitter - TWTR - Hold", @"Zacks Rank: Hold                        TWTR : Twitter",
                    @"The Street Rank: Sell               TWTR : Twitter",
                    @"MarketWatch Rank: Hold           TWTR : Twitter",
                    @"InvestorPlace Rank: Sell          TWTR : Twitter",
                    @"Nasdaq Rank: Hold                     TWTR : Twitter",
                    @"Target Price: $29                    TWTR : Twitter",
                    @"Our Pick - Sell                   TWTR : Twitter",nil];
}
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText.length == 0) {
    isFiltered = NO;
}
else
{
    isFiltered = YES;
    filteredStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSString *str in totalStrings) {
        NSRange stringRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (stringRange.location !=NSNotFound) {
            [filteredStrings addObject:str];
        }
    }
}
[self.myTableView  reloadData];

 }

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
 {
[self.myTableView resignFirstResponder];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
  if (isFiltered) {
    return [filteredStrings count];
}

return [totalStrings count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if (!isFiltered) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [totalStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
else
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [filteredStrings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;

}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

}







- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 @end
```

I would love to hear a response on how to add a segue from each of the results.

Comment: Question, how are your segues setup? In other words, are you performing a segue from the cell to the new view, or from the table view controller (the actual controller, not a specific button or cell) to the new view?

Comment: The actual controller I am trying to make a segue from that. @TooManyEduardos

Answer (score 0):

In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPathMethod`use `performSegueWithIdentifier` to manually call a segue that you created in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to add segue from UITableviewController to next viewController, as as suggested by @blake Lockley perform segue on selection of uiTableviewCell on  didSelectRowAtIndexPath
.